# Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olMSG

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

```
reportPath = "C:\\Test\\"

oApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")

nSpace = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

nSpace.Logon()

oInbox = nSpace.GetDefaultFolder(win32com.client.constants.olFolderInbox)

oItems = oInbox.Items

for i in range(oItems.Count):

        oMsg = oItems.Item(i+1)
        oMsg.SaveAs(reportPath+str(i)+".msg", Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olMSG)
```

`oMsg.SaveAs` fails as `"Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olMSG"` parameter invalid.
What is its equivalent in `win32com`?

Please help

Comment: Tried passing value 3 for 2nd parameter of SaveAs object but no hope.

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass a numeric value (olMSG = 3) instead. Or just remove the second parameter, it is optional.

Comment: Exception, Collection of New Valid emails: SaveAs() got an unexpected keyword argument 'olMSG'

Comment: Did you try to omit the second parameter?

Comment: Yes...it worked excluding 2nd parameter...Thank you for the input

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Eugene Astafiev for driving it. Finally it worked. Steps following.

```
OlSaveAsType = {
    "olTXT": 0,
    "olRTF": 1,
    "olTemplate": 2,
    "olMSG": 3,
    "olDoc": 4,
    "olHTML": 5,
    "olVCard": 6,
    "olVCal": 7,
    "olICal": 8
}
```

&

```
oMsg.SaveAs("C:\\Test\\1.msg", OlSaveAsType['olMSG'])
```