# How do I convert a .msg outlook file to a .txt file with python 3.9?

Tags: python, python-3.x, outlook, win32com

Please help a beginner python student out! I would really appreciate it.

I am trying to automatically filter emails from my inbox and save them as a text document in a specified folder. I can get the emails in my folder as .msg no problem, however, when I try to save it as a .txt file it either a) does not open up normally when I remove 'olTXT' or b) throws me the following error when I add 'olTXT':

```
line 19, in <module>
message.SaveAs(os.getcwd()+'//'+name, olTXT)
NameError: name 'olTXT' is not defined
```

I am using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.saveas as my reference.

This is what I have so far:

```
import win32com.client
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import os
import re

outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.items
message = messages.GetFirst()

report_subject = "Tech Report"

for message in messages:
    if message.subject[0:11] == report_subject:
        name = str(message.subject)
        #to eliminate any special charecters in the name
        name = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', name)+'.txt'
        #to save in the current working directory
        message.SaveAs(os.getcwd()+'//'+name, olTXT)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
OlSaveAsType = {
    "olTXT": 0,
    "olRTF": 1,
    "olTemplate": 2,
    "olMSG": 3,
    "olDoc": 4,
    "olHTML": 5,
    "olVCard": 6,
    "olVCal": 7,
    "olICal": 8
}

# example
message.SaveAs(os.getcwd()+'//'+name, OlSaveAsType['olTXT'])
```

Reference: [Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olMSG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28481263/outlook-olsaveastype-olmsg)

The way you have it now you are referencing a variable *olTXT* before it is ever assigned which is why you are receiving the error.

Comment: That helps a lot thank you! Thanks to your comment, I found the list on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olsaveastype. If you don't mind me asking, is it a function in the win32com module that is hung up on 'olTXT' but knows the reference for '0'?

Comment: The const olTXT = 0 might exist in the win32com library, but I'm not sure. All I know is that previous answers to similar questions used the method of defining it as I have shown.

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question, but ANY function would get hung up on a variable that's passed before it is assigned/initialized. It has no idea what olTXT is.

Comment: If this solves your issue please mark the question as closed and select my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks will do! Sorry just getting used to this sm platform lol

Answer (score 0):

`olTxt` is 0 (`olMsg` is 3, etc.):

```
message.SaveAs(os.getcwd()+'//'+name, 0)
```

Comment: If the reply answers your question, please mark it as such. Thanks!

Comment: You guys both answered my questions but I guess I can only mark one down.